# Android studio making only list of dates selectable in date picker

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

Title, I want to have a list (array, xml, text whatever is easiest) and I want to have only those dates(there are gaps in the dates) in the date picker be selectable. I know how to set the min and max date but nothing for certain dates.

my code so far

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

// Use the current date as the default date in the picker. val c = Calendar.getInstance() val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)



val dialog = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, year, month, day)

dialog.datePicker.maxDate = Date().time

return dialog
}
```

If there is a dialog.dataPicker.addDate or something similar I can work out the for loop for it but any pointers would help, Thanks.

Comment: If third party libraries are an option, it looks like [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) implements a date-time picker widget that has a `setDisabledDays(Calendar[])` method.

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be to create your own class for the datepicker dialog, you can extend the DatePickerDialog and implement your own logic there for handling certain date change events:

```
    class CustomDatePickerDialog(
        // context, date set listener, and list of selectable dates
    ) : DatePickerDialog(context, null, 0, 0, 0) {

    override fun onDateChanged(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        // Here you check if the selected date is in your list
        val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance()
        selectedDate.set(year, month, day)
        val selectedTimeInMillis = selectedDate.timeInMillis
        
        // If it is, call the super.onDateChanged
        if (selectableDates.contains(selectedTimeInMillis)) {
            super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.